# Excel custom cell style remover

Tags: vba, excel

When you only want a couple styles from a workbook but not all of them it's easier to merge styles then remove those you don't want.

How can I improve the form or the backing code?

---

Userform with styles listed.

[image: Userform]

```
'CustomStyleRemoverForm
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ListStyles
End Sub

Private Sub ListStyles()
    CustomStylesListBox.Clear

    Dim listStyle As Style
    For Each listStyle In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        If Not listStyle.BuiltIn Then
            CustomStylesListBox.AddItem listStyle.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAllButton_Click()
    CheckAllBoxes True
End Sub

Private Sub UnselectAllButton_Click()
    CheckAllBoxes False
End Sub

Private Sub InvertSelectionButton_Click()
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 0 To CustomStylesListBox.ListCount - 1
        CustomStylesListBox.Selected(counter) = Not CustomStylesListBox.Selected(counter)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CheckAllBoxes(ByVal updateValue As Boolean)
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 0 To CustomStylesListBox.ListCount - 1
        CustomStylesListBox.Selected(counter) = updateValue
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveSelectedButton_Click()
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 0 To CustomStylesListBox.ListCount - 1
        If CustomStylesListBox.Selected(counter) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Styles(CustomStylesListBox.List(counter)).Delete
        End If
    Next

    ListStyles
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to review, your code is clean.  There are some things that you can do to improve User Experience (UX).

- Replace the label, SelectAllButton and UnselectAllButton with a checkbox.
- Place a Frame around the Controls
- Add a ComboBox to change target workbooks
- Add buttons to copy and paste styles between workbooks

[image]

And if you want to go buckwild you could add a Preview Button

[image]

Comment: For your styles preview did you use a `ListBox`? I can't figure out how to change the BackColor and ForeColor text for each element.

Comment: @IvenBach I used a WebBrowser control using the `CellStyleCSS` class from [Using Excel Cell StyleElements to Style HTML Document](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179439/using-excel-cell-styleelements-to-style-html-document)